# How to set default font for lattice graphics?

Tags: r, lattice

I tried to change fonts for lattice graphics in R:

```
trellis.par.set(list(axis.text=list(fontfamily="Monaco"), par.strip.text=list(fontfamily="Monaco")))
```

It works for `axis.text` but not for `par.strip.text`.
`trellis.par.set()` does not change `par.strip.text` neither `strip.text` while I
can change font for strip text using the option in a individual plot function:

```
xyplot(0 ~ 0 | "Strip Text", par.strip.text=list(fontfamily="Monaco"))
```

How do you change font for strip text globally at once? Or can you change default font globally for all text elements of lattice graphics?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the font in the *device* to which you are printing:

```
?pdfFonts
# on a Mac
?quartzFonts  # for the interactive device
# on NIX boxen
?x11
?X11Fonts
```

Comment: Thanks. `pdf(family="Monaco")` generates plots with the specified font as expected. But `quartz(family="Monaco")` or `quartzFonts(sans = quartzFont(rep("Monaco", 4)), serif = quartzFont(rep("Monaco", 4)))` do not change fonts for on-screen plots.

Comment: There is also a `trellis.device()` and the settings for grid graphics are often passed to the trellis device along the lines of `gp=gpar(fontfamily="Times")`

Comment: `trellis.device(device="quartz", family="Times")` has no effect on lattice plots to screen. Could you please give an instruction how to use it?